# Rendering the dom outside the viewport in safari IOS

Tags: dom, safari, viewport

Working on a one page app in html5, I'm using transform: translate3d to navigate between the different pages.

for one of this page I call an ajax request to feed it with a list of 150 elements.
After injected those elements, I show it with: translate3d(0, 0, 0)

This works for android, and all desktop browser, even safari, iphone safari load the list only after the page appearance.
so instead of 
call Ajax => inject in hidden Page => show hidden Page
it goes like
call Ajax = show hidden Page >=> inject in hidden Page

In both case the data are present in step 2.
When I reduce the number of Data it works fine

so it's seems that create the DOM when it's outside the viewport is slow rendering in safari Ios, maybe some one experimented the same problem ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

solved:

-webkit-transform: transform3d(0, 100%, 0) put the page outside the viewport.
Safari on IOS seems to be slow rendering what he can't see, so I use this: 
-webkit-transform: transform3d(0, 99%, 0) and it works perfect.

This page is empty so no problem to let 1% in the viewport.

Lot of issues with Safari on IOS with that rendering.